Convert rich text to json text object and create a csv with all objects inside one "cell"
EDIT: Nevermind, I figured out everything with two python scripts!!!
I'm trying to convert my 30-chapter book into a .csv file where every "cell" is a different chapter that also preserves the rich text formatting. I see this as three steps: 1. split the original book into 30 documents, 2. convert each document into correctly formatted text, 3. recombine them into a single spreadsheet that can be exported as .csv.
I can accomplish the first step by using Microsoft Word's outlining to create subdocuments. The split function correctly creates 30 documents with one heading and the full content of the files. They are even helpfully labeled "Chapter 1", "Chapter 2".
I am now stuck on steps 2 and 3.
[EDIT:  I HAVE SOLVED STEP 2 AND 3 WITH TWO PYTHON SCRIPTS]
Step 2:
Each paragraph needs to be wrapped in some json object code with no hard returns (or stripped out in a later step) so they will all remain in a single spreadsheet cell.
The wrapper needs to follow this format (I think!):
{"type":"root","children":[{"type":"paragraph","children":
[{"type":"text","value":"Paragraph one, sentence one. Sentence two. Sentence three."}]},{"type":"paragraph","children":
[{"type":"text","value":"Paragraph two, sentence one. Sentence two. Sentence three."}]},{"type":"paragraph","children":
[{"type":"text","value":"Paragraph three, sentence one. Sentence two. Sentence ten or whatever."}]},
{"type":"paragraph","children":
[{"type":"text","value":"Paragraph four, this sentence is in italics.","italic":true}]}]}

So as you can see there is a wrapper around each paragraph as well as around the whole chapter-document and there are NO HARD RETURNS ANYWHERE IN THE SCRIPT.
Step 3: I don't know how to do this at all. [EDIT #2: The answer was, again, a Python script]
Other desires:
a. I need to strip out the heading 1 of each document. It exists in the original document and is necessary for Microsoft Word's outline splitter to work, but after I do not want any h1 or chapter identification in the final text. It's already labeled in its destination. [EDIT: THIS WAS ALSO SOLVED WITH THE PYTHON SCRIPT]
b. I need the document name to go into the spreadsheet in this format: chapter_1, chapter_2, chapter 3, epilogue, etc. [PYTHON FOR THE WIN]
Screenshot of desired output for .csv:
Thank you so much for any ideas!
